# Higher dimensional trapped surface and its condition?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, gravitational-waves

In higher D-dimensional spacetime, a marginally trapped surface is a closed spacelike (D-2)-surface whose outer null normals have zero convergence. It is very like a marginally trapped surface in the 4-dimensional spacetime.

Now, in the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0201034, the authors tried to find a marginally trapped surface before the collision of two black holes moving at the speed of light. Assume they are moving parallel to $z$ and in the opposite directions. Define retarded and advanced times $(u,v)=(t-z,t+z)$.

The metric is given by

$$ds^2=-dudv+[H^{(1)}_{ik}H^{(1)}_{jk}+H^{(2)}_{ik}H^{(2)}_{jk}-\delta_{ij}]dx^idx^j$$

where $H^{(1)}_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+\nabla_i\nabla_j\Phi(\vec x-\vec x_1)u\theta(u)$ and $H^{(1)}_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+\nabla_i\nabla_j\Phi(\vec x-\vec x_2)v\theta(v)$. Here, $\vec x_1$ and $\vec x_2$ are the transverse coordinates of the two black holes. $\Phi(\vec x-\vec x_a)$ is some function. $\nabla_i$ represents partial derivative and $i$ is the index for the transverse coordinates. $\theta(u)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Starting from the paragraph containing Equation (17), the authors tried to construct the trapped surface $\mathcal S$ in the union of two null hypersurfaces $v\le 0=u$ and $u\le 0=v$. In the first null surface $v\le 0=u$, $\mathcal S$ is defined by

$$v=-\Psi_1(\vec x)$$

then they stated that for $v<0$,

$$\nabla^2(\Phi_1-\Psi_1)=0$$

where I think $\Phi_1=\Phi(\vec x-\vec x_1)$.

Then I tried to verify this relation. In the region $v<0$, the metric is now

$$ds^2=-dudv+H^{(1)}_{ik}H^{(1)}_{jk}dx^idx^j$$

and it is easy to check the vector field $k^a=(\partial_v)^a=(0,1,\vec 0)$ is the null geodesic generator of the hypersurface $u=0\ge v$. And $l^a=2(\partial_u)^a=(2,0,\vec 0)$ is another null vector such that $l_ak^a=-1$. It is easy to check that the expansion of $k^a$ is zero,

$\theta_{(k)}=g^{ab}\nabla_ak_b=0=\Gamma^a_{av}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial\sqrt{-g}}{\partial v}$

because the metric is independent of $v$. The expansion of $l^a$ is more complicated, and you can check that, after some manipulation,

$\theta_{(l)}=\Gamma^a_{au}=-2\mathrm{Tr}(h)/u$

where $h$ is some matrix which is related to $\nabla\Phi_1$ but does not depend on $v$! This causes a big problem, because if $h$ is not a function of $v$, I cannot determine the relation between $\nabla^2\Phi_1$ and $\nabla\Psi_1$. Did I made some mistake here? How shall I use the definition of $\mathcal S$: $v=-\Psi_1(\vec x)$?